# Without evaluating accessor detect if Object.defineProperty has a chained data descriptor

Tags: javascript, descriptor

In the example code below I would like to detect if a property ('cv') is further chained to other descriptors. When dealing with data descriptors this goes down a rabbit hole and there is no end coz JS keeps returning data descriptors infinitely. In cases where there is an accessor somewhere deep in the chain we can detect it by testing if accessor functions are defined.

The objective is to copy the value property of a descriptor using the value property's descriptor, save it somewhere and use a accesor descriptor to access the saved value later. But then this needs to be done without actually invoking any deep level accessor inadvertently ( which ends up returning a computed value which will eventually be stale). The following will not work

```
var newDescriptor = {
  value : oldDescriptor.value
}
```

The following

```
var newDescriptor = {}
Object.defineProperty(newDescriptor, value, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(oldDescriptor, 'value'));
```

may work but ends up with a pileup of unnecessary descriptor chains when called again and again which may eventually eat up memory. But then this solution also requires detection if such a chain was already setup for a descriptor and possibly reduce them by picking up the leaf level data descriptors. Which brings us to the data descriptor rabbit hole!

The real use case is to convert an existing data descriptor to an accessor descriptor when an apparent data descriptor may not be so and already has a deep level accessor chained. I am probably missing other better ways of solving this.

Code Sample

```
var ob = {cv : 5};
console.log(" ob.cv : " + ob.cv ); // Returns 5  
var cvd1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ob, 'cv');
console.dir( cvd1 ); 
var cvd2 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cvd1, 'value');
console.dir( cvd2 ); 
var cvd3 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cvd2, 'value');
console.dir( cvd3 ); 

// Deepest chained accessor descriptor
var deepAccessorDescriptor = {};
Object.defineProperty(deepAccessorDescriptor, 'value', { 
  get  : function() { return 74 ; }
} );

// Chained data descriptor
var chainedDataDescriptor = {};
Object.defineProperty(chainedDataDescriptor, 'value', deepAccessorDescriptor );
Object.defineProperty(ob, 'cv', chainedDataDescriptor);
console.log(" ob.cv : " + ob.cv ); // Returns 74 from deepAccessorDescriptor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descriptors cannot be chained. It's as simple as that.

When you call `Object.defineProperty`, it doesn't store the descriptor object you passed - it just looks at it and stores the relevant things in the attributes of the property.

When you call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, it doesn't access a previously stored object. It checks the attributes of the property, and *creates a new object* with plain data properties to describe the attributes.

```js
var deepDescriptor = {};
Object.defineProperty(deepDescriptor, 'value', { 
  get() {
    console.log("evaluated");
    return 74;
  }
});
console.log("descriptor created");
var ob = {};
Object.defineProperty(ob, 'cv', deepDescriptor);
console.log("property defined");
console.log("ob.cv", ob.cv);
```

You can see that the `deepDescriptor.value` getter is evaluated during the `Object.defineProperty(…, deepDescriptor)` call, not during the `ob.cv` access.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It was not apparent and intuitively felt that the ob.cv access was causing it. It is though expect that any descriptor getter should not get called unless explicitly accessed through the property by at the script level. defineProperty probably isn't where one would expect this to happen irrespective of whether chaining by design is restricted.

Comment: @user2994430 `defineProperty` just accesses `deepDescriptor.value` - it doesn't care what kind of property that is on the descriptor object